# how to make parseIt in javaRAP?

Tags: java

I want work with javaRAP but i can't make parseIt.I have this error:

C:\Users\zahra\Documents\bllipparser-2015.08.18\first-stage\PARSE>make parseIt

```
g++     parseIt.C   -o parseIt

In file included from InputTree.h:24,
             from parseIt.C:31:
SentRep.h:22: istream: No such file or directory

SentRep.h:24: ostream: No such file or directory

make: *** [parseIt] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Install Charniak's parser (version parser05Aug16).

> $ make parseIt

If you encounter the following error message, you may want to try
overwriting the files in the PARSE/ subdirectory of the parser with
those provided in the parser05Aug16.patch.zip zipfile.

[wing.nus@cte PARSE]$ make

/usr/bin/g++  -c -O BchartSm.C

BchartSm.C:30: error: expected initializer before ‘*’ token

BchartSm.C: In member function ‘float Bchart::computepTgT(int, int)’:

BchartSm.C:612: error: ‘globalGi’ was not declared in this scope

make: *** [BchartSm.o] Error 1

Get the latest JavaRAP

(http://aye.comp.nus.edu.sg/~qiu/NLPTools/JavaRAP.html), decompress
it, and modify env.jrap *carefully*. It's important that you add "./"
as a directory prefix even it seems unnecessary.

Try:

> $ java -jar AnaphoraResolution.jar testdata/SimpleTest.txt

Comment: yes i know this , but i don't know how to make it!!! i think it's more complex than this simple command $ make parseIt

Comment: Error - `from parseIt.C:31` is that correct? The error suggests, you are missing file in the path.